# Protect FTP using iptables from brute force

Tags: ssh

I use this code to protect my ssh.

```
*filter
-N SSH_CHECK
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j SSH_CHECK
-A SSH_CHECK -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 -j ACCEPT
-A SSH_CHECK -m recent --set --name SSH
-A SSH_CHECK -m recent --update --seconds 900 --hitcount 2 --name SSH -j DROP
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m limit --limit 25/minute --limit-burst 100 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 25 -j DROP
-A INPUT -p udp --dport 25 -j DROP
COMMIT
```

How can I add port 21 to this list?

If I use

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j SSH_CHECK
```

Is it same as using port 22?

Answer (score 2):

You can rate-limit new FTP connections from a host using the same method you're rate limiting FTP. I'd create another chain (something like `FTP_CHECK` rather than `SSH_CHECK`) and you'll want to use another list (say `FTP` rather than `SSH`) to keep the incoming FTP host addresses separate from SSH addresses. Something like:

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j FTP_CHECK
-A FTP_CHECK -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 -j ACCEPT
-A FTP_CHECK -m recent --set --name FTP
-A FTP_CHECK -m recent --update --seconds 900 --hitcount 2 --name FTP -j DROP
```

Two FTP connections in 900 seconds is a little bit strict, though, in my opinion. I'd open that up a little bit more or legitimate users may find that, should they get disconnected, they won't be able to reconnect. Tune to suit your needs.